# The significance of the Bool value of PFUser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfobject, pfuser

I am wondering what is the significance of the **succeeded** Bool value in the function block? As I have seen sample codes from parse ignores it and only check if error is nil or not.

If the bool value is not required, why is it there in the first place?

```
        user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if succeeded { // IS THIS REQUIRED AT ALL??
                }
            }
            else {
            }
        });
```

Or we could just do this?

```
        user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                //Do something
            }
            else {
            }
        });
```

Comment: It sure seems like they ought to be synonymous.

Comment: If error is nil, is it possible for the bool to be false in some circumstances? Thats what is confusing.